# sos berlin scheduler -- job chain - how to trigger other job after job timeout

Tags: timeout, scheduled-tasks, kill, job-scheduling

I'm using sos berlin scheduler (version linux-x64 1.10.5).

Normally when job in job_chain timeout, scheduler will kill the job process and send a email.
So, based on this, I want to trigger other job. 
But, I have tried two ways all doesn't work.

***Way 1:***

Add a function “spooler_task_after()” in the job.

I guess the failure is because this job will create a process on linux system, while job timeout scheduler kill this job process, also kill the function “spooler_task_after()”

Code:

```
<job timeout="00:00:09">
    <script language="shell"><![CDATA[

    echo aa
    sleep 10s
    echo bb

    ]]></script>
    <monitor name="exit_code" ordering="0">
    <script language="java:javascript"><![CDATA[

    function spooler_task_after(){
       var exitCode = spooler_task.exit_code;
       spooler_log.info ("Exit Code is: " + exitCode);

       /*
        call other job
       */

       result = true;
      return result;
    }

            ]]></script>
    </monitor>
    <run_time/>
</job>
```

Result:

```
2017-07-27 21:22:21.251+0800 [info]   
2017-07-27 21:22:21.251+0800 [info]   Task sample_errorhandling/job1:23026 - Protocol starts in /httx/opt/sos-scheduler/ldw-scheduler-test1/logs/task.sample_errorhandling,job1.log
2017-07-27 21:22:21.250+0800 [info]   SCHEDULER-842  Task is going to process Order sample_errorhandling/job_chain3:12, state=aaa, on JobScheduler 'http://xxxx:4444', Order's Process_class
2017-07-27 21:22:21.268+0800 [info]   SCHEDULER-726  Task runs on this JobScheduler 'http://jt-host-kvm-72:4444'
2017-07-27 21:22:21.268+0800 [info]   SCHEDULER-918  state=starting (at=never)
2017-07-27 21:22:22.466+0800 [info]   SCHEDULER-987  Starting process: '/bin/sh' '-c' '"/tmp/admin/sos.gBdCm8"'
2017-07-27 21:22:23.520+0800 [info]   [stdout] aa
2017-07-27 21:22:30.326+0800 [ERROR]  SCHEDULER-272  Terminating task after reaching deadline <job timeout="9">
2017-07-27 21:22:30.359+0800 [ERROR]  SCHEDULER-202  Connection to task has been lost, state=running_remote_process: Z-REMOTE-101  Separate process: pid=0: Connection lost / zschimmer::com::object_server::Connection::pop_operation
2017-07-27 21:22:30.359+0800 [ERROR]  SCHEDULER-202  Connection to task has been lost, state=release: Z-REMOTE-122  Separate process pid=0: Caller has killed process
2017-07-27 21:22:30.384+0800 [ERROR]  SCHEDULER-280  Process terminated with exit code 1 (0x63)
2017-07-27 21:22:30.384+0800 [WARN]   SCHEDULER-845  Task ended without processing the order. The order remains in job's order queue in the same state
2017-07-27 21:22:30.384+0800 [info]   SCHEDULER-843  Task has ended processing of Order sample_errorhandling/job_chain3:12, state=aaa, on JobScheduler 'http:/xxxx:4444'
```

***Way 2:***

Add return code on job chain node

This way works on job execute successfully or with error. But failed when job was killed with timeout.

Code in job chain:

```
<job_chain >
    <job_chain_node  state="aaa" job="job1" next_state="success" error_state="error">
        <on_return_codes >
            <on_return_code  return_code="1">
                <add_order  xmlns="https://jobscheduler-plugins.sos-berlin.com/NodeOrderPlugin" job_chain="/error_handling/sendmail"/>
            </on_return_code>
        </on_return_codes>
    </job_chain_node>

    <job_chain_node  state="success"/>

    <job_chain_node  state="error"/>
</job_chain>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the error_state= attribute. 
When JobScheduler kills the task because of a timeout this is handled as an error situation.

Please note the the next_state of the errorHandling state is error to indicate in JOC that this was an error and that the errorHandling state have its own error_state to indicate if the errorHandler itself fails.

```
 <job_chain>
     <job_chain_node  state="100" job="job1" next_state="200" error_state="errorHandling"/>
     <job_chain_node  state="200" job="job2" next_state="success" error_state="errorHandling"/>
     <job_chain_node  state="errorHandling" job="errorHandlerJob" next_state="error" error_state="errorInErrorHandling"/>
     <job_chain_node  state="success"/>
     <job_chain_node  state="errorInErrorHandling"/>
     <job_chain_node  state="error"/>
 </job_chain>
```